# Как сделать ховер эффект как на этом сайте?https://www.bt-comfort.ru/

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать ховер эффект как на этом сайте?https://www.bt-comfort.ru/

может есть  плагины или решения

Answer (score 2):

запустите сайт в хроме (к примеру), нажмете F12 и посмотрите как устроен сайт:

1. задний фон рисуется через `canvas`
2. внутри `canvas` рисуются svg объекты стрелочки
3. в зависимости от координат мыши вычисляется поворот стрелочки вокруг своей оси и цвет закраски от синего до красного

Comment: А как можно узнать скрипт вычисления позиции мышки? Если такое возможно буду премного благодарен

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_clientx.asp, https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+get+mouse+coordinates+in+javascript - тут с кодом